# Create Pattern 2^34 and store data

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sympy

We have written script which 2^n pattern(create truth table) and check with output.it is mainly use for determine circuit behavior. if you have 2^n input what should be output in those case.(based on some logic operation)

it was working fine till 2^16 but As complexity increase Input has increase from 2^16 to 2^34.
So We need to create truth table for such a big number and process data.

The issue here,When I tried to traverse data but after 1 day application got crash with printing any thing. it may be stack overflow or memory error.

My question is, Can we store such a big number in Python data. or Can we create truth table for such a big number.(using sympy or other library).

One solution suggest us, Store into database or file for 2^34 number truth table and read from database and process it.So we can save time for generating truth table.

is it possible to store such huge number.

let me know if I need to provide more info or code snippets

```
  #here is in_ary is :[CK,Q0,Q1......Q32]
    def input_patterns(io_ary,in_ary):
        Num_patterns = pow(2,34)
        fn_patt = fn_patt = lambda i: i
        patts = {}

        i = 0
            while i < Num_patterns:
                i = i +1
                io_patt, in_patt = [], []
                while (1):
                    ii = fn_patt(i)
                    if not patts.has_key(ii):
                        patts[ii] = ii
                        break
                for j in range(num_ins):
                    state = ii & 1
                    globals()[in_ary[j]] = state
                    in_patt.append(state)
                    ii = ii >> 1
                if Invalid_equation and eval(Invalid_equation) & 1 == 1:
                    Num_patterns = Num_patterns - 1
                    continue        # if Qualifier is false do not include this pattern
                patterns.append(io_patt + in_patt)
                return patterns
```

**Output**
**This is not of 2^34 bit but 2^16 out**

```
 <Input Pin>                             <output pin>
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Yes, it is expected that you post some of your code and additional info. You can read what you should add here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What is density of your t-table (what is proportion between 1 and 0 in output)? Could you post couple (~5) of rows from your table?

Answer (score 0):

```
## Prints a list 
import itertools
n = 5
table = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n))
print table
```